# How can I copy code from GoDaddy's cPanel to a private GitHub repository?

Tags: git, github, synchronization, godaddy-api

I made my own GitHub private repository on github.com, and my website is being hosted on GoDaddy. I saw that the GoDaddy cPanel has Git Version control but it states "Create and manage Git™ repositories. You can use Git to maintain any set of files and track the history of changes from multiple editors (version control)."

How can I copy the website's code from GoDaddy and place it onto my GitHub repository?

Thanks!